# TCP adapter in spring integration check closu

Tags: spring-integration

In 
`AbstractByteArraySerializer` why we need this method?

```
protected void checkClosure(int bite) throws IOException {
    if (bite < 0) {
        logger.debug("Socket closed during message assembly");
        throw new IOException("Socket closed during message assembly");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this, it's generally best to explain why you are asking it - like are you experiencing some problem that you are trying to understand.

TCP is a streaming protocol; we need some way to delimit a message from the stream, for example `CRLF`; that's what the (de)serializers do - serializers add structure to the stream, deserializers decode the messages from the stream.

We need to detect if the client closes the socket before a complete message is received.

If you wish the client to signal the end of the message by closing the socket, then you can use the `ByteArrayRawSerializer`.

Comment: Sorry.  I am trying to see that is my understanding is correct or not. It seems like I got it correct. Thank you, Gary. The reason is that, We are continuously getting socket message assembly exception. However, the app where it has been deployed into two different environments. In one environment I m experiencing this issue but on the other I am not. Hw can I verify or validate at the client whether socket is closed or not. I have used  ByteArrayRawSerializer & I don't see the exception bt whenever I convert the received bytes into String, we see weird characters in non-human readable format.

Comment: It's really hard to track down intermittent problems like that; you would probably need to use a network monitor like wireshark to look at the packets on the wire.

Comment: I have used wireshark. I have the screenshot. Can I attach it here?

Comment: If client doesn't closes the socket before a complete message is received. So does adapter ends up throwing socket message assembly exception? I am getting the exception continuously.I have tried with all available serializer/deserializer in integration. It didn't work. But When I try to ByteArrayRawSerializer. It accepts some data but some junk charaters.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what the client is sending. The only way this exception is thrown is if the client closes the socket without having sent a properly-formed frame of data.

Comment: The client is sending CDR (Call Data Record). The format is shown below:

Comment: NULLNULLNULL1613 0003 7    8 1599         3249999    4493661                            1     023 4          1         0 1 0                  CRLF

Comment: Does the environment matters? Because we did our testing on windows server 2008 R2. and we are deploying it to Windows server 2012 R2. I am not able to figure out why I am not getting socket assembly issue in one environment and why I am getting it on other environment

Comment: The environment does not matter. I need to see your wireshark capture file to help further; you need to find somewhere to post it in a zip. It's not clear whether you mean "CRLF" or "\r\n" in your above example; if "CRLF" you need to add something to the end to delimit the data. If the client is only sending one packet then closing the file, use the raw serializer.